# change safari audio output device

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

I want to change the audio output device *only* for Safari.app.

How do I do that?

I know I can change system-wide settings, that's not helpful to me.

I am hoping for a macOS built-in, code-injection or very lightweight invisible third-party app solution.

Comment: [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) would be my go-to app for anything like that, but not cheap.

Comment: @Tetsujin I already have it but it's annoying to have to run it for something as basic as this